# Scheduling Query Execution For Determined Time

Tags: mysql, events, process, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to schedule the execution of some queries on a pre-definided time?... 
This is what kind of need to do: 
Let's suppose that I have some queries, that I need to be executed in a definided time, and thus, the result will be on cache. 
Let's say, I need to create a demon/event/script: 
If day is equal to 2 and time is equal to 2:00am, then
    select * from books; 
    select * from users; 
    ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE EVENT foo ON SCHEDULE EVERY MONTH STARTS '2012-10-02 02:00:00' DO
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM books;
    SELECT * FROM users;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need... I guess I can tu put many queries, not just one after "DO"...

Comment: @user1600801: You can use compound statements if they are enclosed in a block such as `BEGIN ... END` - see above.  However, beware that results are only retrieved from the query cache if the query is *identical*; it's pointless to cache these queries since the results can merely be read directly from the tables anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advices. I already studied how cache works... I really appreciate you help